# Convert HEX to Signed INT Javascript

Tags: javascript, signed-integer

I am trying to convert this HEX value `fba46c58` to a signed int then take that number and divide it by `1000000`. I have tried the following code but I don't seem to come up with the correct number. Overall I need the end number to equal `-73.11044`

Tried this code:

```js
let testd = parseInt("fba46c58", 16)
if ((testd & 0x8000) > 0) {
    testd = testd - 0x10000;
}

// Getting: 4221856856 / 1000000 = 4221.856856
// Want to get: -73.11044
```

Any help would be amazing thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468474/javascript-convert-a-hex-signed-integer-to-a-javascript-value/34679269

Comment: That's where I got the above code -  however it did not solve my issue. Thus this new question.

Comment: You're looking for the signed two's compliment conversion, right?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146177/convert-a-signed-decimal-to-hex-encoded-with-twos-complement

Comment: Thank you @Seanonymous - that worked for me!